# MVC QueryString parameters suddenly not reading after &amp;

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

This method, which takes in new invitations, has always worked.  Suddenly this morning, it's not working.  Debug shows that the method is not picking up `&amp;`

this is the URL (note the parameter division by `&amp;`):

```
http://localhost:1212/Account/HandleInvitation?guid=56cfbb11-6507-4cf4-aecf-a58f3e1a37a8&amp;email=email@address.com&amp;usertype=Vendor&amp;vendorid=0
```

this is the method sig:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult HandleInvitation(string email, string guid, UserType userType = UserType.None, int vendorId = 0)
    {
```

The result is that 'guid' gets set because it is first in the url...everything after the first & is ignored.  The incoming is from SendGrid and I can't be sure if they've always looked like this or if the encoded ampersand is something that changed recently.

I know I could just manually decode or parse the URL in the first line of the method but my worry is that something somewhere got altered and this might be a system-wide issue for any other url encoded parameters.

So my question is: is there a setting somewhere that affects this and how can I fix it so the parameters get assigned properly like they used to?

Thanks

Comment: `&amp;` is an HTML escape code.  It should not appear in URLs.

Comment: oh, ok...well that's weird.  SendGrid must be encoding the email, including the "accept invite" button url

Comment: Is your email HTML or plain text? The email client will decode HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Well I never did figure out what changed to cause the URL to HTML encode but I fixed it by turning off click tracking in SendGrid